added spacing in first element in Dialog composable
i have this composable that i created:
it contains a dialog composable and inside it, it contains a column that contains itself Text composables:
@Composable
fun MediaOptionsDialog(
launch: RocketLaunchUi,
onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {

val context = LocalContext.current

Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
            )
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.article),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    if (launch.articleLink.isNotEmpty()) {
                        context.openUrl(launch.articleLink)
                    }
                    onDismiss()
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
        )

        HorizontalDivider()

        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.wikipedia),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    if (launch.wikipedia.isNotEmpty()) {
                        context.openUrl(launch.wikipedia)
                    }
                    onDismiss()
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
        )

        HorizontalDivider()

        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.video),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    if (launch.videoLink.isNotEmpty()) {
                        context.openUrl(launch.videoLink)
                    }
                    onDismiss()
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
        )
    }
}

as you can see i've added the same vertical padding to Texts, no padding was provided to any parent composable but this is how it looks:

what could be the issue? i fixed the height of Texts and many things but nothing worked.

The code looks fine. This is most likely caused by an unintended line break in your strings.xml. It probably looks something like this:
<string name="article">Article\n</string>

Note the \n indicating a newline. Removing it should also remove the extra spacing you see in the UI.
